# Reduced time complexity of inner loop: Find count of elements greater than current element in the first loop and store that in solved array

Tags: java, arrays, collections, stack, queue

I want to reduce the complexity of this program and find count of elements greater than current/picked element in first loop (`array[]`)and store the count in solved array(`solved[]`) and loop through the end of the array[]. I have approached the problem using a general array based approach which turned out to have greater time complexity when 2nd loop is huge. 
But If someone can suggest a better collection here in java that can reduce the complexity of this code that would also be highly appreciated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    if (i < input - 1) {
        count=0;
        for (int j = i+1; j < input; j++) {
            System.out.print((array[i])+" ");
            System.out.print("> ");
            System.out.print((array[j]) +""+(array[i] > array[j])+" ");
            if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        solved[i] = count;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    System.out.print(solved[i] + " ");
}
```

**What I want to achieve in simpler terms**

**Input**

Say I have 4 elements in my

array[] -->86,77,15,93

**output**

solved[]-->2 1 0 0

2 because after 86 there are only two elements 77,15 lesser than 86

1 because after 77 there is only 15 lesser than 77

rest 15 <93 hence 0,0

Comment: Actually, the title of the question is the opposite of the body, where you actually look for the count of elements less than the current one.

Comment: @yeppe The time complexity of Leo's algorithm is nlogn + (n-1)log(n-1) + ... + 2log2 + 1log1 = O(n^2*logn), which is actually higher than your solution (even though the code is definitely more elegant). You can check the calculation e.g. at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121997/the-asymptotic-behaviour-of-sum-k-1n-k-log-k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a `O(n*logn)` solution, but you should use a self balancing binary search tree such as red-black tree.

**Main idea of the algorithm:**

You will iterate through your array from right to left and insert in the tree triples `(value, sizeOfSubtree, countOfSmaller)`. Variable `sizeOfSubtree` will indicate the size of the subtree rooted at that element, while `countOfSmaller` counts the number of elements that are smaller than this element and appear at the right side of it in the original array.

*Why binary search tree?* An important property of BST is that all nodes in the left subtree are smaller than the current node, and all in the right subtree are greater.

*Why self-balancing tree?* Because this will guarantee you `O(logn)` time complexity while inserting a new element, so for n elements in array that will give `O(n*logn)` in total.

When you insert a new element you will also calculate the value of `countOfSmaller` by counting elements that are currently in the tree and are smaller than this element - exactly what are we looking for. Upon inserting in the tree compare the new element with the existing nodes, starting with the root. **Important:** if the value of the new element is greater than the value of the root, it means that is also greater than all the nodes in the left subtree of root. Therefore, set `countOfSmaller` to the `sizeOfSubtree` of root's left child + 1 (because the new element is also greater than root) and proceed recursively in the right subtree. If it is smaller than root, it goes to the left subtree of root. In both cases increment `sizeOfSubtree` of root and proceed recursively. While rebalancing the tree, just update the `sizeOfSubtree` for nodes that are included in left/right rotation and that's it.

Sample code:

```
public class Test
{  
    static class Node {
        public int value, countOfSmaller, sizeOfSubtree;
        public Node left, right;
        public Node(int val, int count) {
            value = val;
            countOfSmaller = count;
            sizeOfSubtree = 1; /** You always add a new node as a leaf */
            System.out.println("For element " + val + " the number of smaller elements to the right is " + count);
        }
    }
    static Node insert(Node node, int value, int countOfSmaller)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return new Node(value, countOfSmaller);

        if (value > node.value)
            node.right = insert(node.right, value, countOfSmaller + size(node.left) + 1);
        else
            node.left = insert(node.left, value, countOfSmaller);

        node.sizeOfSubtree = size(node.left) + size(node.right) + 1;

        /** Here goes the rebalancing part. In case that you plan to use AVL, you will need an additional variable that will keep the height of the subtree.
            In case of red-black tree, you will need an additional variable that will indicate whether the node is red or black */

       return node;
    }
    static int size(Node n)
    {
        return n == null ? 0 : n.sizeOfSubtree;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {    
        int[] array = {13, 8, 4, 7, 1, 11};
        Node root = insert(null, array[array.length - 1], 0);
        for(int i = array.length - 2; i >= 0; i--)      
           insert(root, array[i], 0); /** When you introduce rebalancing, this should be root = insert(root, array[i], 0); */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So making the code simpler and making the code faster aren't necessarily the same thing. If you want the code to be simple and readable, you could try a sort. That is, you could try something like

```
int[] solved = new int[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    int[] afterward = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, i, array.length);
    Arrays.sort(afterward);
    solved[i] = Arrays.binarySearch(afterward, array[i]);
}
```

What this does it it takes a copy of the all the elements after the current index (and also including it), and then sorts that copy. Any element less than the desired element will be beforehand, and any element greater will be afterward. By finding the index of the element, you're finding the number of indices before it.

A disclaimer: There's no guarantee that this will work if duplicates are present. You have to manually check to see if there are any duplicate values, or otherwise somehow be sure you won't have any.

**Edit:** This algorithm runs in *O(n<sup>2</sup> log n)* time, where *n* is the size of the original list. The sort takes O(*n log n*), and you do it *n* times. The binary search is much faster than the sort (*O(log n)*) so it gets absorbed into the *O(n log n)* from the sort.  It's not perfectly optimized, but the code itself is very simple, which was the goal here.

Answer (score 3):

With Java 8 streams you could reimplement it like this:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 86,77,15,93 };
int[] solved =
  IntStream.range(0, array.length)
           .mapToLong((i) -> Arrays.stream(array, i + 1, array.length)
                                   .filter((x) -> x < array[i])
                                   .count())
           .mapToInt((l) -> (int) l)
           .toArray();
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could do _Mathematica_ programming in Java now.

Answer (score 0):

As Miljen Mikic pointed out, the correct approach is using RB/AVL tree. Here is the code that can read and N testcase do the job as quickly as possible. Accepting Miljen code as the best approach to the given problem statement.

```
class QuickReader {
    static BufferedReader quickreader;
    static StringTokenizer quicktoken;

    /** call this method to initialize reader for InputStream */
    static void init(InputStream input) {
        quickreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        quicktoken = new StringTokenizer("");
    }

    static String next() throws IOException {
        while (!quicktoken.hasMoreTokens()) {
            quicktoken = new StringTokenizer(quickreader.readLine());
        }
        return quicktoken.nextToken();
    }

    static int nextInt() throws IOException {
        return Integer.parseInt(next());
    }

    static long nextLong() throws IOException {
        return Long.parseLong(next());
    }

    static double nextDouble() throws IOException {
        return Double.parseDouble(next());
    }
}

public class ExecuteClass{
    static int countInstance = 0;
    static int solved[];
    static int size;

    static class Node {
        public int value, countOfSmaller, sizeOfSubtree;
        public Node left, right;

        public Node(int val, int count, int len, int... arraytoBeused) {
            countInstance++;
            value = val;
            size = len;
            countOfSmaller = count;
            sizeOfSubtree = 1; /** You always add a new node as a leaf */
            solved = arraytoBeused;
            solved[size - countInstance] = count;
        }
    }

    static Node insert(Node node, int value, int countOfSmaller, int len, int solved[]) {
        if (node == null)
            return new Node(value, countOfSmaller, len, solved);
        if (value > node.value)
            node.right = insert(node.right, value, countOfSmaller + size(node.left) + 1, len, solved);
        else
            node.left = insert(node.left, value, countOfSmaller, len, solved);
        node.sizeOfSubtree = size(node.left) + size(node.right) + 1;
        return node;
    }

    static int size(Node n) {
        return n == null ? 0 : n.sizeOfSubtree;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        QuickReader.init(System.in);
        int testCase = QuickReader.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i <= testCase; i++) {
            int input = QuickReader.nextInt();
            int array[] = new int[input];
            int solved[] = new int[input];
            for (int j = 0; j < input; j++) {
                array[j] = QuickReader.nextInt();
            }

            Node root = insert(null, array[array.length - 1], 0, array.length, solved);
            for (int ii = array.length - 2; ii >= 0; ii--)
                insert(root, array[ii], 0, array.length, solved);

            for (int jj = 0; jj < solved.length; jj++) {
                System.out.print(solved[jj] + " ");

            }
            System.out.println();
            countInstance = 0;
            solved = null;
            size = 0;
            root = null;
        }

    }
}
```